# The person who create data have only access to modify And other can only view it in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I want to make setting  The person who create data have only access to modify And other can only view it in SHAREPOINT.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to list / library setting page, you will get this configuration option. There you will see the option who can edit.... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Under ADVANCED SETTINGS in the LIST SETTINGS menu, you will see options for ITEM-LEVEL PERMISSIONS.  This is what you want.  You can specify which items users are allowed to read, create, and edit.

Comment: I tried that way as well but its not working! I want like let say You create Chapter1 Data and I create Chapter2 data. So I can see your Chapter1  but i cant modify it , same way you can see mine but you cant modify it.

Comment: Make sure you grant the correct group permissions overall.

Answer (score 0):

1) As mentioned by others, list advanced settings

[image]

2) Use unique permission for the list/library

3) Permission for this list

Grant **Edit-Add** (Edit-Add - Can view, add, and update.  Cannot delete.) permission 
   to users or groups that the users are in.

Answer (score 0):

Just as others saying, item-level permission is the best solution for you.

**Read all items**
If this is checked, everyone who has access to the list will be able to read any items, whether they were created by the user logged in or someone else. That means that John will be able to read Mary’s entries and vice versa. This is the default behavior of a SharePoint list.

**Create items and edit items that were created by the user**
If this is checked, both John and Mary will be able to create items, but John will only be able to edit items he created and Mary will only be able to edit items she created.

I think this shall be what you want.

Reference:[How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/)